# Understanding pointed value-assignment C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Good morning/evening everyone,

I'd like to clear the following pointer-concept,

In this prototype I'm passing the first value copying this first parameter x given in the main,and the second one I'm passing it through reference so I'm directly access its memory cell to change it permanently.

What I don't get (in the function) is how the function manages the values,

I'll try to be more specific, i don't understand how much those assignments are ''cyclic''.

For example this function seems a kind of swap function to me because takes x that is and integer and assign to x the value pointed by y, that is the value pointed in turn by y+1, and so on.

So I'd like to know when this sequence of assignments starts and ends, to understand why whether i print it in the main or in the function it printf always If I'm not mistaken {11,33,22,44}

```
void Boh(int x,int *y)
{
    x = *y;
    *y = *(y+1);
    *(y+1) = x;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {11,22,33,44};
    Boh(a[0],&a[1]); \* (Point 1) *\
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Passing value to `x` is pointless because you change it in first statement: `x = *y;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that the parameter `x` to the function is immediately overwritten with the value of `*y`.  So whatever value is given for this parameter is irrelevant to the result.

The function is swapping `*y` and `*(y + 1)` using `x` as a temporary.  Because the parameter `y` corresponds to `&a[1]` in `main`, that's the first location that gets swapped.  If you then swap in `&a[1]` for `y` in the expression `*(y + 1)`, you get  `*(&a[1]+ 1)` == `*((a + 1) + 1)` = `*(a + 2)` = `a[2]`.  So `a[1]` and `a[2]` are getting swapped, which it what you'll see if you print the contents of the array after calling `Boh`.